# While loop printing integers under condition

Tags: python, while-loop, integer

So I was trying to write a basic while loop to print out integers strictly greater than `num1` and strictly less than `num2` but it seems that my code is off. Could someone help me out?

```
i=0
while i>num1 and i<num2:
    print(i)
    i+=1
```

Comment: And what are values of num1 and num2 ?

Comment: what is the value of `num1` and `num2`?

Comment: they can be any values, just assume num1 < num2

Comment: Then what is the error? You should have to make sure `num1 < i < num2`

Comment: Could just do `print(*range(num1+1, num2)), sep'\n')`? if you wanted. Note the key thing here is `range` that does a lot of work for you (it already excludes the end), so you just add one to the start and loop over it and then you don't need to initialise i, can change the while to a for, and don't need to remember to increment `i`

Comment: or use a for loop... `for i in range(num1+1, num2): print i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `i` to `num1+1` instead of `0`.

If `i` is less than `num1` to begin with then the loop would never be executed.

Comment: Okay, so set i to num1+1 or anything thats greater than num1 to work the loop?

Comment: @user2963578 Yes, it should be _between_ the two values.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure `num1` < `i` < `num2`.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at the [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function. You can loop between two numbers using range and you dont have to do the increments by hand.

```
for i in range(num1+1, num2):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after giving a value for num1 and num2, I suppose that num1&num2 are not initialized in you program.

**code**

> i=0
>
> num1=-5
>
> num2=10
>
> while i>num1 and i< num2:
>
> ```
>     print(i)
>
>     i+=1
> ```

**output**

> python  /tmp/test.py
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4